# Best way to get values from a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Apologies for the potentially noobish question.

I have this dict:

```
info = {'a': [u'option1'], 'b': [u'option2', u'option3'], 'c': [], 'd': [], 'e': [], 'f': [u'option4', u'option5', u'option6', u'option7', u'option8', u'option9', u'option10', u'option11'], 'g': [], 'h': []}
```

I need to make a query with each value.
In Python what is the best way to get the values?

I currently do this:

```
keys = info.keys ()
for i in keys:
    for j in info [i]:
        # Make query with j
```

I think it can be done better.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you please elaborate "I need to make a query with each value"?

Comment: Of course, I need to make a query by sending that element as a parameter. Ex `query = sql.get_price (j)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through the keys and values of a dict using [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).

```
for i, js in info.items():
    for j in js:
        # Make query with j
```

(In Python 2 you might prefer to use [`iteritems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) instead of `items()`.)

If you don't need to make use of the keys at all, you could just use [`values`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) (or [`itervalues`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) for Python 2).

```
for js in info.values():
    for j in js:
        # Make query with j
```

Maybe a list comprehension would work for you; it is impossible to tell without knowing what "Make query with j" entails.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to iterate over the list elements in every value? If you don't use the key, you can use [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) directly:

```
>>> [option for v in info.values() for option in v]
['option1', 'option2', 'option3', 'option4', 'option5', 'option6', 'option7', 'option8', 'option9', 'option10', 'option11']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, value in info.items():
    #do something with either the key, value or both
```

Comment: No explanation given.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2.x

```
for key,values in info.iteritems():
    print keys,values
```

Using **dict.iteritems()** you can iterate through the keys and values in dictionary and make queries or anything.

Dict: name of the dictionary*

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
for vals in info.values():
    for j in vals:
        # make queries with j
```

You can get the list of all the values like this:

```
values = [x for vals in info.values() for x in vals]
```

Then you can use

```
for j in values:
     # make queries with j
```